# What charger to use with my ZIPPY Compact 6200mAh 4s 40c Lipo MultiRotor Battery

Tags: quadcopter, battery, lithium-polymer

Hello I am trying to build a Quadcopter for a school project and I need to finish quick before our mission trip because I was asked to finish it before then so that I could take it. But I am having a problem figuring out which charger would work with my [ZIPPY Compact 6200mAh 4s 40c Lipo Pack](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__63431__ZIPPY_Compact_6200mAh_4s_40c_Lipo_Pack.html?gclid=CMqXo9W_hskCFY-VfgodACwH9w)

---

Here are the specs on the battery

- Capacity: 6200mAh
- Voltage: 4S1P / 4 Cell / 14.8V
- Discharge: 40C Constant / 50C Burst
- Weight: 589g (including wire, plug & case)
- Dimensions: 158x46x41mm
- Balance Plug: JST-XH
  Discharge Plug: HXT4mm

---

Also I will be running the [Tarot T4-3D Brushless Gimbal for GoPro (3-Axis)](http://www.helipal.com/tarot-t4-3d-brushless-gimbal-for-gopro-3-axis.html?gclid=CJuvxaGj5MgCFYeEfgodtWkOaA)
and if anyone can tell me a good battery to run it off of or maybe it would be better to run it off my main battery.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ben, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 2):

Buy the imax b6. They're cheap to replace at $26, I would recommend buying the imax b6 with the built-in power supply as it saves you having to buy an extra 12v 5A psu. I own 4 imax b6's and they work wonders.

Comment: Thank you user2769025 I will look into this. I was originally thinking it would cost me more then $70 but this will leave me with enough money to buy an extra FPV kit.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4962)